# Reduce debug output from CoreData?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-data

I'm working on a iOS/macOS project where I'm using CoreData. It works fine, but it outputs enormous amounts of debugging info to the Console. This makes the Console unusable, since my print statements are buried in all the CoreData related stuff.

I have a pretty simple CoreData setup with fetching of some data, so these are not errors, just general event logs it seems. I have the same results on other projects I have used CoreData.

**Any way to reduce/remove this logging to the console?**

Some sample data ([all data here](https://gist.github.com/eivindml/75f9f3cbe76e1cef7c3f2a33e39c9c85)):

```
CoreData: warning: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _

performExportWithRequest:]_block_invoke_2(946): Finished export: <PFCloudKitExporter: 0x2838bd840>
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _finishedRequest:withResult:](2102): Finished request: <NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest: 0x2823bbb40> DC26CDEE-0AB6-42CD-81E5-996E7E7727F9 with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x282dfcfa0> success: 1 madeChanges: 0 error: (null)
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _scheduleAutomatedExportWithLabel:activity:completionHandler:]_block_invoke(2170): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x281ae4580> - Finished automatic export - AppActivationExport - with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x282dfcfa0> success: 1 madeChanges: 0 error: (null)
CoreData: warning: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate finishedAutomatedRequestWithResult:](2115): Finished request '<NSCloudKitMirroringExportRequest: 0x2823bbb40> DC26CDEE-0AB6-42CD-81E5-996E7E7727F9' with result: <NSCloudKitMirroringResult: 0x282dfcfa0> success: 1 madeChanges: 0 error: (null)
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest](2073): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x281ae4580>: Checking for pending requests.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate checkAndExecuteNextRequest]_block_invoke(2088): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x281ae4580>: No more requests to execute.
CoreData: CloudKit: CoreData+CloudKit: -[NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate _scheduleAutomatedImportWithLabel:activity:completionHandler:](2140): <NSCloudKitMirroringDelegate: 0x281ae4580> - Beginning automated import - ImportActivity - in response to activity:
<CKSchedulerActivity: 0x280ec8f00; additionalXPCActivityCriteria={
    Priority = Utility;
}
```

Comment: I have that already added, and it doesn't change anything. :/

Comment: @eivindml did you ever find a good solution?

Comment: @MeaganS. No, unfortunately. :/ I have tried all solutions mentioned here. I also tried to move all CoreData logic to a framework, but it still logs everything. Would love to know if you figure something out. :) Added a bounty to get some more attention to this.

Comment: Do you have a reproduction path?

Comment: @J.Doe I'm pretty sure it happens if you create an empty project and check to include the basic CoreData/CloudKit option, adds an Entity to the Model, then read/write something.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try adding these as launch arguments see if it helps

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 0
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 0               
-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 0
-com.apple.CoreData.MigrationDebug 0
```

EDIT1:
I found this in Apple docs:
Choose Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme. Select an action such as Run, and select the Arguments tab. Pass the com.apple.CoreData.CloudKitDebug user default setting with a debug level value as an argument to the application.
[image: Like this]

```
 -com.apple.CoreData.CloudKitDebug 0
```

Add this last one as a launch argument and you should achieve what you wanted.

[link to the AppleDocs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/syncing_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit)
Check the section named **Debug Errors in Core Data with CloudKit**

Comment: Thank you very much! That finally works, and it also gives me more control so that the debugging can actually be useful. 

Comment: Thank you, having to search the flood of output from CloudKit and CoreData for things I actually needed to log was driving me insane

Comment: This works fine for iOS, but for some reasons logs keep showing up when running watchOS apps (launch arguments passed to watch app).

Comment: I had tried .CloudKitDebug from Apple's docs with no luck, but using all 5 arguments finally did the trick

Comment: Great answer. Worked like a charm for me - Xcode 12.x , macOS11.

Answer (score 32):

I had the same problem.
This will disable CoreData debug output:
in 'Arguments passed on launch':
`-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 0`

Worked for me.

Comment: Accepted answer didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps in Xcode:

1. Products
2. Scheme
3. Edit scheme...
4. Chose left side your way of building the app (I guess Run)

I guess you will see `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` in 'Arguments passed on launch'. If you see that, turn it off. If you don't see it, add:

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
```

Values and descriptions:

1. SQL Statements, Row count and Execution time
2. Bind values and the
   truncated version of NSSQLiteStatement that does not list the full
   list of Managed objects.
3. List of Managed Objects returned for the
   query. These objects have not been faulted into memory and therefore
   only the Managed Object ID is outputted.
4. SQLite Explain Query Plan

From http://blog.raymccrae.scot/2017/12/core-data-sqldebug-log-levels.html

Comment: This was the best answer last I checked a few years ago. I found the output to be excessive even on the most minimal logging setting, but maybe it's good enough for OP.

Comment: Unfortunately that just made it worse. It displays the same CoreData logs, but sprinkles it with SQLite logging data as well. :/